# France visa processing in vfs bangalore

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

The french consulate had requested me to submit additional documents for visa processing.

I submitted on May 10th.

My question is, does anyone have any idea how much time it take after additional documents submission?

My travel date is May 25th.